# Hiding a component on some pages VueJs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to hide 2 components (AppBar & NavigationDrawer) included on my App.vue from some routes like /login.

I already included this in my NavigationDrawer.vue but it's disabling the component on every routes :

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    permanent
    color="#2e3336"
    height="100vh"
    expand-on-hover
    v-if="!['Login'].include($route.name)">
```

Do I use the rigth method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `$route.name === 'Login'`, as $route.name is the current route name, so you can check directly like this.